# Javascript Regex get each matching

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I want to find each youtube link in a page. I found on StackOverflow some regex i modified but when i have a html code with two youtube linq the result is one match like

`youtube.com?v=videoid<div></div>youtube.com?v=videoid2`

I want to get each youtube link only.

My regex is :

```
/(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&amp;]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([\w|-|_]{11})/
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks and sorry for bad english.

Comment: `input.split(/(?:<[^<>]+>)+/)`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor and sorry for duplicate answer

Comment: I decided to give you one because you actually tried something and no need to be sorry for a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

try to add 'g' modifier at the end of the regular expression like so:

```
/(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&amp;]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([\w|-|_]{11})/g
```

That means globally (get all matches)

Comment: I doubt you really mean to use `[?&amp;]` as it matches either `?` or `&`, or `a`, or `m`, or `p` or `;`.

Comment: i mean to use the /g modifier in order to get all occurences of the regular expression matches.
The rest of the regex come from Pascal Mormin, i just copy / pasted it to give a full fonctionnal example

Comment: `[\w|-|_]` im pretty sure this should be `[\w-_]` as otherwise it matches alphanumeric, _, -, |

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I chose to add /g and split the string. It seems to be good. mystring.match(/(https?:\/\/)?(www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|(e(?:mbed)?)|watch)\/|.*v=)|youtu\.be\/)([\w-_)]{11})/g)[0].split(/(?:<[^<>]+>)+/)